# Fail to start Portainer agent with error "Unable to retrieve advertise address"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I ran followimng command to deploy Portainer on a Win Server 2019 (V1809).

Deploy Portainer Agent on a standalone Windows Server 2016 Docker Host

$ docker run -d -p 9001:9001 --name portainer_agent --restart=always -v .\pipe\docker_engine:.\pipe\docker_engine portainer/agent

How should I resolve the "Unable to retrieve advertise address" error?

Here is the agent container log:

2019/05/29 12:21:14 [ERROR] - Unable to retrieve advertise address: Unable to retrieve the address on which the agent can advertise. Check your network settings

2019/05/29 12:22:16 [ERROR] - Unable to retrieve advertise address: Unable to retrieve the address on which the agent can advertise. Check your network settings

2019/05/29 12:23:18 [ERROR] - Unable to retrieve advertise address: Unable to retrieve the address on which the agent can advertise. Check your network settings

2019/05/29 12:24:20 [ERROR] - Unable to retrieve advertise address: Unable to retrieve the address on which the agent can advertise. Check your network settings

2019/05/29 12:25:21 [ERROR] - Unable to retrieve advertise address: Unable to retrieve the address on which the agent can advertise. Check your network settings

Answer (score 0):

Following command works.

docker run -d -p 9001:9001 --name portainer_agent --restart=always -v .\pipe\docker_engine:.\pipe\docker_engine portainerci/agent:develop